# Booking train tickets on RENFE site

Tags: trains, tickets, spain

Trying to book tickets from Madrid to Seville on RENFE site. The options I can see there differ significantly in price, depending on the service provider. AVE trains are generally more expensive, but I can at least book them.

There are two options I really want to book: Alvia or Intercity:

[image]

But when I try to book them I get this error: *Tarifas no disponibles en el trayecto y fechas seleccionadas. Pruebe con otras fechas. Inc 3471 (F063)*

In fact, I tried other dates, even next Monday or mid November, and I'm still getting the same error for any Alvia train.

Should I wait for tickets to be released? Or should I give up and book a ticket for an AVE train?

Answer (score 3):

As your post was written the 13th of September, at this time there were many rains and floods in the east of Spain and a lot of trains were cancelled. When this happen, the Renfe web page is not working properly and it is better if you call to Customer Support and buy the tickets with them.

Other option is to travel by bus, you can use this web [www.alsa.com](https://www.alsa.com) to buy the tickets

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same and had the same issues. I was booking a train from Barcelona to Amsterdam,

So Instead I opted to book out of a site called https://www.thetrainline.com/ which actually shows different train options. Please see if this works for your case.

Check this screenshot for more info. I have opted the same date as you mentioned. It is costing about 23 Euros for a single trip.

https://gyazo.com/124e42e6e347afc1ee2f8633ad36e85d

Comment: I need 2 tickets, and when I search for two adults, I don't see that train on trainline at all! But on RENFE site, it doesn't let me buy even 1 ticket for that train! Does that mean that only 1 ticket is available?

Comment: I agree that the train is not available for 2 adults at 9.45.That could mean only 1 ticket is available. But there seems to be one more cheap option at 8.30. Check this screenshot. https://gyazo.com/d03f7c63fa060cda869fd491de2c30a5

Comment: Did this work for u ?

Comment: It's a mess, I don't see that option on trainline anymore. I instead see even cheaper option for 47.30 euros, but I cannot book it even on Trainline site: https://imgur.com/jsgpV9q

Comment: Hmm. Then it maybe a problem with the Renfe servers. wait for a day n check again